# How to select in PostgreSQL table where an attribute is not NULL?

Tags: postgresql, null, isnull

I have this [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org) table, test:

```
 a | b | c | d 
---+---+---+---
 5 |   | 5 | 7
 5 | 6 |   |  
 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

I want to query all tuples whose b value is not NULL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test WHERE b != NULL;
SELECT * FROM test WHERE b <> NULL;
```

The two commands both have no return records:

```
 a | b | c | d 
---+---+---+---
(0 rows)
```

What command should I use to select all tuples that has a b value?

Comment: Please see [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html).

Answer (score 5):

## `IS NOT NULL`

Use this command:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test WHERE b IS NOT NULL;
```

The result is:

```
 a | b | c | d 
---+---+---+---
 5 | 6 |   |  
 1 | 2 | 3 |  
(2 rows)
```

## Standard SQL

Both predicates `IS NULL` & `IS NOT NULL` are standard SQL ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Null-specific_and_3VL-specific_comparison_predicates)). So they work in Postgres as well as other compliant databases.